# Contact form not returning proper information

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, email, contacts

I'm currently working through setting up a fully functional contact form using the Bootstrap framework and PHP.  I'm receiving test emails from the form but it's not displaying the content the way I understood it would and I'm having some other issues.

First, the user-submitted email is showing up as being received from the host of my site.  It is also not including the name of the person, which I thought I included in my PHP

[image: Screenshot of email field returned as number]

Here is my code for contact.php and the form in my index.html file

```
<?php 

$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];

if ($_POST){
mail($to, $subject, $message);
$confirm= "Your email was sent successfully!";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('$confirm');</script>";
}
else {
    $error_msg= "All fields are required!";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$error_msg');</script>";
}
?>
```

index.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="contact.php" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h2>Contact</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                <!--name-->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="First and Last Name">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                <!--email-->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@somewhere.com">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                <!--subject-->
                <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="subject" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Enter subject here...">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                <!--message-->
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="msg" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Enter message here..."></textarea>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                </div>
          </form>
```

Another unintended issue is that once the page is submitted, a blank page (contact.php) is loaded.  I thought, looking at my code, a javascript alert or confirm box would pop up instead though?  I'm new at this so, I apologize if these are dumb questions.

Thanks
-K

Comment: Simple answer: Use proper headers and a valid `From:` email address. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You're not doing anything with name or email in contact.php. As for the javascript not working, most likely, you're not rendering a proper HTML document and so it won't work. Do a view source and see what the HTML looks like when you send.

Comment: And just taking what the user enters in a form and using it without checking it is ripe for security problems.

Comment: As I said I'm new at this so I haven't even considered security issues.  What are some topics I can look into that cover this?  Would it be form validation?

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you don't have from defined in your header. You need

```
$headers = "From: sender_email@your_domain.com\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

You can also modify header to send html message which is desired in most cases in addition to setting from and cc: carbon copy or bcc: blind carbon copy email addresses.

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Get this code incorporated in your if statement. I also noticed you have

```
else {
    $error_msg= "All fields are required!";
```

Even if there was only one field passed in as $_POST method, the else statement isn't checking if all fields were passed in. You need to break that down or check the fields individually or do it on with client side JavaScript field validation.

What is the confirm javascript function? can you post it on here? if you're only looking for an alert, you can straight insert alert function in between script tags.

Comment: Thanks, so I would pass $name<$email> into the headers variable?
    
`$from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        
$subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        
mail("example@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: yes you would. you should do it this way: $name.' <'.$email.'>'; you show call the last arg in the mail function $header since you can add other things such as html email or when you decide to add cc: or bcc: in the $header and not just define from: name and email address